# My icons and text are scrambled

Tags: 20.04

Sometimes, after some screen refresh, or after closing and opening the lid, all my icons and text are scrambled like so:
[Scrambled text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDkNv.png)
[Scrambled icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc3aW.png)

The thing is I don't exactly know how to describe it, but that they are scrambled. So I didn't really find a google answer yet. Does anyone know where to start?

Im working on a dell precision (7540 I think), on ubuntu 20.04. Thanks in advance.

I've got a systemd error log by executing:

```
grep -i -e fail -e error -e corrupt /var/log/syslog

Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop containerd[1616]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:14.524123647+01:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (ext4) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop containerd[1616]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:14.524356199+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop containerd[1616]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:14.539170434+01:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop containerd[1616]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:14.539199751+01:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop containerd[1616]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:14.543262466+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to load cni during init, please check CRI plugin status before setting up network for pods" error="cni config load failed: no network config found in /etc/cni/net.d: cni plugin not initialized: failed to load cni config"
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop colord[1600]: failed to get session [pid 1520]: No data available
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop colord[1600]: message repeated 2 times: [ failed to get session [pid 1520]: No data available]
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333754.9018] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333754.9029] dispatcher: (1) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:14 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333754.9081] dispatcher: (2) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:15 robin-dell-laptop wpa_supplicant[1557]: nl80211: kernel reports: Attribute failed policy validation
Feb  3 07:29:15 robin-dell-laptop wpa_supplicant[1557]: Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlp111s0: -22 (Invalid argument)
Feb  3 07:29:15 robin-dell-laptop wpa_supplicant[1557]: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp111s0
Feb  3 07:29:15 robin-dell-laptop wpa_supplicant[1557]: P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
Feb  3 07:29:15 robin-dell-laptop wpa_supplicant[1557]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface.P2PDevice dbus_property=P2PDeviceConfig getter failed
Feb  3 07:29:15 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333755.0167] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:4 'up' [wlp111s0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333760.6947] dispatcher: (4) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:5 'connectivity-change', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333760.6951] dispatcher: (5) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop mount[1932]: error 2 (No such file or directory) opening credential file /home/robin/.smbcredentials
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop systemd[1]: media-x\x2ddrive.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/x-drive.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop systemd[1]: remote-fs.target: Job remote-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:6 'dhcp6-change' [wlp111s0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333760.6984] dispatcher: (6) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop systemd[1]: Finished Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:7 'connectivity-change', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:20 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333760.9120] dispatcher: (7) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:9 'up' [br-5804d9798349], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.0281] dispatcher: (9) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:11 'up' [br-5f4ffd250782], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.0578] dispatcher: (11) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:13 'up' [br-986db107cc58], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.0906] dispatcher: (13) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:15 'up' [br-36e94fc22922], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.1239] dispatcher: (15) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:17 'up' [br-3ed05ea835fc], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.1510] dispatcher: (17) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:19 'up' [br-598ee9b1499a], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.1819] dispatcher: (19) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:21 'up' [br-95d4ef8f7695], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.2125] dispatcher: (21) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:23 'up' [br-ee792a8390d6], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.2443] dispatcher: (23) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:25 'up' [docker0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop NetworkManager[1522]: <warn>  [1612333762.2758] dispatcher: (25) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error status 127.
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:22.360416659+01:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint ee792a8390d6e492bcdeed100600806bcad413d14fdd5f0927240f9a8e6623f6 8293a69ec2509bf12acecbd89dbd3ee35d93123567f821f63ba54039dfef0203], retrying...."
Feb  3 07:29:22 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:22.616715751+01:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint ee792a8390d6e492bcdeed100600806bcad413d14fdd5f0927240f9a8e6623f6 5d9fc7ff7d3d3dc992003e31dc8697a433d315cd08dc72172f6e33c28066ce79], retrying...."
Feb  3 07:29:23 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:23.280322274+01:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint ee792a8390d6e492bcdeed100600806bcad413d14fdd5f0927240f9a8e6623f6 d5ed2d8ebaa9eb6711a09e6b9ec62d11f363ffcd35aa00fa5247bded814872a7], retrying...."
Feb  3 07:29:23 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:23.648487427+01:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Feb  3 07:29:23 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:23.648505256+01:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Feb  3 07:29:23 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:23.806167297+01:00" level=error msg="649f7b63cddb46e87d7e76bf47c52ac0476e8b1fefde1817fb302ce9a353147d cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Feb  3 07:29:23 robin-dell-laptop dockerd[1924]: time="2021-02-03T07:29:23.806249096+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to start container 649f7b63cddb46e87d7e76bf47c52ac0476e8b1fefde1817fb302ce9a353147d: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:449: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\\\\\"/home/robin/projects/edata-util/docker_template/mysql/mysqld.cnf\\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ec69a10d67c0cca3b5c53695fb965f28abe041921757d0daf779cf4abade9889/merged\\\\\\\" at \\\\\\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ec69a10d67c0cca3b5c53695fb965f28abe041921757d0daf779cf4abade9889/merged/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf\\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\\"not a directory\\\\\\\"\\\"\": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type"
Feb  3 07:29:29 robin-dell-laptop at-spi-bus-laun[5457]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method “RegisterClient”
Feb  3 07:29:29 robin-dell-laptop indicator-sound[5520]: volume-control-pulse.vala:735: unable to get pulse unix socket: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service files
Feb  3 07:29:29 robin-dell-laptop indicator-sound[5520]: media-player-list-greeter.vala:51: Unable to get active entry: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.UnityGreeter was not provided by any .service files
Feb  3 07:29:29 robin-dell-laptop indicator-keybo[5516]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Feb  3 07:29:36 robin-dell-laptop dbus-daemon[5425]: [session uid=121 pid=5425] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' failed: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1
Feb  3 07:29:36 robin-dell-laptop indicator-sound[5520]: Failed to connect to proxy
Feb  3 07:29:43 robin-dell-laptop kernel: [   37.825520] systemd-journald[707]: File /var/log/journal/e942a52f34514c37816ba86bfe425383/user-1001.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Feb  3 07:29:43 robin-dell-laptop dbus-daemon[6277]: [session uid=1001 pid=6277] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1001 pid=6333 comm="zenity --warning --no-wrap --text=Error found when" label="unconfined")
Feb  3 07:29:43 robin-dell-laptop at-spi-bus-launcher[6341]: dbus-daemon[6341]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1001 pid=6333 comm="zenity --warning --no-wrap --text=Error found when" label="unconfined")
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session-x11@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session@gnome-initial-setup.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session-pre.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session-initialized.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session@gnome-login.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session-x11.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop systemd[6253]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Feb  3 07:29:46 robin-dell-laptop gnome-session-c[6885]: Error creating FIFO: File exists
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop gsd-usb-protect[7080]: Failed to get screen saver status: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.ScreenSaver without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop gnome-shell[6908]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop gsd-media-keys[7061]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-random
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop gsd-media-keys[7061]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop gsd-media-keys[7061]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop gsd-media-keys[7061]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop colord[1600]: failed to get session [pid 7055]: No data available
Feb  3 07:29:48 robin-dell-laptop colord[1600]: failed to get session [pid 7055]: No data available
Feb  3 07:29:49 robin-dell-laptop gnome-shell[6908]: Error registering session with GDM: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.DisplayManager was not provided by any .service files
Feb  3 07:29:53 robin-dell-laptop fwupd[7737]: ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/esys_context.c:69:Esys_Initialize() Initialize default tcti. ErrorCode (0x000a000a)
Feb  3 07:29:53 robin-dell-laptop tracker-miner-f[5415]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Feb  3 07:29:53 robin-dell-laptop tracker-miner-f[5415]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Feb  3 07:29:53 robin-dell-laptop tracker-miner-f[5415]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Feb  3 07:29:53 robin-dell-laptop indicator-sound[5520]: g_object_ref: assertion 'old_val > 0' failed
Feb  3 07:29:54 robin-dell-laptop snap-store[7206]: not handling error failed for action get-updates-historical: failed to build result for 96b9d5c39390e7d3010d15f70854344310dffefc
Feb  3 07:30:01 robin-dell-laptop pulseaudio[6268]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Feb  3 07:30:12 robin-dell-laptop spotify[10699]: Failed to load module "gail"
Feb  3 07:30:12 robin-dell-laptop spotify[10699]: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Feb  3 07:30:12 robin-dell-laptop spotify[10699]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Feb  3 07:30:18 robin-dell-laptop gnome-shell[11175]: 2021-02-03 07:30:18,890 ERROR [main] davmail  - Unable to set log file path
Feb  3 07:30:18 robin-dell-laptop gnome-shell[11175]: 2021-02-03 07:30:18,891 ERROR [main] davmail  - Unable to set log file path
Feb  3 07:31:36 robin-dell-laptop nautilus[12258]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Feb  3 07:34:06 robin-dell-laptop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[13601]: _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
Feb  3 07:34:06 robin-dell-laptop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[13601]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Feb  3 07:34:06 robin-dell-laptop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[13601]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 13601 does not belong to any known session
Feb  3 07:34:08 robin-dell-laptop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[13607]: dbus-daemon[13607]: [session uid=120 pid=13607] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

As requested (note it does the same on a docking station with 2 added screens)

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117GLM [Quadro T2000 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:188 memory:b4000000-b4ffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:b5000000-b507ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:153 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C display`? This will report some information about your display adaptors, making it a bit easier for someone to offer specific support 

Comment: Any more information someone might need? I've added the command output.